# This was the first time I had ever cleaned the flat. Right tense?

Tags: word-choice, tenses, past-tense

I write in the past and I'm not sure whether it's:

1. This was the first time I had ever cleaned the flat.
2. This had been the first time I had ever cleaned the flat.

In the present it would be: *This is the first time I have ever cleaned the flat*.

I'm not sure how to express it when writing in the past

Comment: Google Books seems to have as many written instances of [*"was the first time I ever"*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22was+the+first+time+I+ever%22) as it does of [*"was the first time I **had** ever"*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22was+the+first+time+I+had+ever%22), but I'm finding it hard to imagine any possible ***semantic*** difference there. But would Roberta Flack have got anywhere if she'd sung [*The First Time I Had Ever Seen Your Face*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqW-eO3jTVU)? I kinda doubt it! :)

Comment: We often omit the helping verb have with utterances like: This was the first time I ever [simple past] etc. But it is lurking there.

Comment: So both is correct?

Comment: "This was the first time I had ever cleaned the flat." and "This was the first time I ever cleaned the flat." both sound natural to me, whereas "This had been the first time I had ever cleaned the flat." does not. It's common in less formal contexts to use simple past tense in many situations where a TEFL teacher or strict grammarian would recommend past perfect.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Comment: Reserve "had been" for special times when you are setting one past action against another even further in the past: a past and an older past. You wouldn't need two older-past. *I **had been** waiting a whole hour when he arrived, and I was annoyed*.